# Dictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Entity>> Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my Application I've got a Dictionary with `int` as key and `ObservableCollection` as value:

```
Dictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Entity>> SourceDict { get; set; }
```

Now I want to bind the Dictionary to a `Datagrid` where all `ObservableCollections` of this `Dictionary` should be presented.

If I bind it like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SourceDict}"
```

I get a empty `Datagrid`. Is there a way to do this or before binding should I convert the `Dictionary` to an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Represented how? At the moment each item of the `DataGrid` is of a `KeyValuePair<int,  ObservableCollection<Entity>>` type

Comment: My Entity class has some properties. These Properties should be represented in the datagrid. Every KeyValuePair in my context is a week. Every week has its own Entities which are located in the ObservableCollection of the KeyValuePair. Now I want to be able to show all the Entities of every week in the datagrid at the same time.

Comment: Either flatten your list to you have list of `Entity` or create outer list like `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` bound to `SourceDict` and inner `DataGrid.ItemsSource` bound to `Value`

Comment: If I flatten the Dictionary and change something in the DatagridCell, it will only be reflected to the flatted list, right? Not to the dictionary?

Comment: `Entity` is a class (guess), so reference type. It doesn't matter where it is as long as it's the same instance. Also if `DataGrid` is empty at the moment then you have some other problem. You should have wrong data, or no data but there should be rows in `DataGrid` reflecting number of weeks

Comment: The `DataGrid` is always filled, it can't be empty..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123092/discussion-between-dkozl-and-f-baum).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="525" Margin="0,42,0,52" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gv_Listview">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".3" Margin="-6,-3">
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Age}" Height="30" Margin="6,3" Width="90"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".3" Margin="-6,-3">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtAriza" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Margin="6,3" Width="112"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Surname">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".3 .3 .0 .3" Margin="-6,-3">
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Surname}" Height="30" Margin="6,3" Width="60"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

this is the TestEntity

```
public class TestEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name ;
    private string _surname;
    private int _age ;

    public string Name
    {
      get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
      get { return _surname; }
        set { _surname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Surname"); }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And DataContext

```
 private List<ObservableCollection<TestEntity>> _source = new List<ObservableCollection<TestEntity>>();
    public List<ObservableCollection<TestEntity>> SourceList
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set { _source = value; }
    }
    public DataContext()
    {
        this.SourceList.Add(new ObservableCollection<TestEntity> { new TestEntity { Age = 21 , Name = "Chris" , Surname = "James"}});
        this.SourceList.Add(new ObservableCollection<TestEntity> { new TestEntity { Age = 23, Name = "Jin", Surname = "Evelin" } });
        this.SourceList.Add(new ObservableCollection<TestEntity> { new TestEntity { Age = 33, Name = "Ryan", Surname = "Thrusty" } });
        this.SourceList.Add(new ObservableCollection<TestEntity> { new TestEntity { Age = 34, Name = "Martin", Surname = "Riggs" } });
    }
```

Hope this helps.